# How can I parse charset value from the JAX-RS response?

Tags: http, character-encoding, client, jax-rs, content-type

On any `Response` whose `Content-Type` might have `charset` property,
How can I parse the value?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: plain/text; charset=<UNKNOWN>
```

When clients need to parse as `Reader`, how can they detect the `charset` value?

```
Response response = request();
try (InputStream stream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
     InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, ????);
     BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone can use the [MediaType#getParameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#getParameters--).

```java
final MediaType mediaType = response.getMediaType();
// mediaType may be null
final Map<String, String> parameters = mediaType.getParameters();
final String charset = parameters.get("charset");
// charset, again, may be null
```